# Managed object store failed to create persistent store coordinator

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

We are getting the following error on a small portion of our beta testers and haven't been able to find a clue of why this is happening:

Managed object store failed to create persistent store coordinator:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x1f5cd8b0 
{NSUnderlyingException=authorization denied, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=23}
```

This happens after the app is launched in the background due to a location event and when we call `addPersistentStoreWithType`. This is how I'm passing the options:

```
NSDictionary *persistentStoreOptions = [NSDictionary 
   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      NSFileProtectionNone, NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey, nil];
NSError *error;
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator 
      addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                   configuration:nil 
                             URL:storeURL 
                         options:persistentStoreOptions 
                           error:&error]) {
...
}
```

Any clue on why this would happen only for a percentage of installs and the reason behind it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845790/how-to-debug-handle-intermittent-authorization-denied-and-disk-i-o-errors-wh

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Core Data across multiple threads? Any chance these users are getting multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinator instances when they should not? I have seen this problem before, in particular with slower devices, and it turned out to be that the code controlling "lazy instantiation" of the persistent store coordinator was not as thread safe as it should be.

Comment: I do use multiple threads but by this point in the code other threads should have not been created yet. Should I try a @synchronized around this part of the code to see if it resolves the problem? In general how do you improve the thread safety?