# Crash core data - NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256

Tags: core-data, crash

I frequently get a crash in testflight builds. Below log is reported in crashlytics for the crash:

> Fatal error: Unresolved error
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256
>   "The file ####.sqlite” couldn’t be opened."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D73975F3-ED76-4C7B-A30A-0C751C8471AA/Library/Application Support/####.sqlite, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=23},
>   ["NSFilePath": /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D73975F3-ED76-4C7B-A30A-0C751C8471AA/Library/Application Support/####.sqlite, "NSSQLiteErrorDomain": 23]:
>   file /Users/elanarulaj/Desktop/voxer_client/packages/sdk.swift/VoxerKit/VoxerKit/Classes/####SDK.swift, line 86

I do not find any working solution in StackOverFlow

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12845790/3985749) and its answers - they might help.